# Definining a class to reference when generating classes from xsd files

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I have a situation where multiple xsd files have the same type of element, for example a DeviceExtension. When generating the classes from the xsd files normally every class will contain the following code verbatim, because all DeviceExtensions are the same.

```
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "")
        public static class DeviceExtension {

            @XmlAttribute(name = "Name", required = true)
            protected String name;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "Value", required = true)
            protected String value;
            @XmlAnyAttribute
            private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

            /**
             * Gets the value of the name property.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            /**
             * Gets the value of the value property.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }
```

I would like to find a solution where I can specify some sort of external binding where I can have this DeviceExtension class in one place, and when the classes are generated from the xsd they reference the one implementation of DeviceExtension.

I have been attempting to find a solution using http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html but I don't understand how to accomplish what I need.

Ideally I would like a simple example that I could follow and modify for all situations where I have this type of case.

Comment: Can you refactor the schemas to centralize the definition of the common types in a single XSD and then `<include/>` that in other XSDs that need to use those types?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to edit the schemas in any way, as they are also used for projects in other languages

Comment: Are you using any external binding configuration files?

Comment: Not currently, I have been reading about them but I can't seem to find any examples detailing what I would like to accomplish.

Comment: So you haven't tried compiling all schemas to the same package?

Comment: Currently, all generated classes are separated into individual packages because the root element for all schemas is the same. This causes every generated class to overwrite the previous if they are created in the same package.